# I can't connect MySQL version 8 to Django 2.2 project

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-8.0, django-2.2

I have tried pretty much everything, including scouring StackOverflow to solve this issue yet I still seem to be faced with the problem. I am trying to connect my Django 2.2.6 project to my MySQL version 8 database with zero luck.

I have changed the settings.py file to contain the following key value pairs in the databases dictionary:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'portfoliodb',
        'USER': 'c**********s',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

typing

```
python manage.py runserver
```

returns the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I do in fact have mysqlclient, typing

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

returns the following:

```
requirement already met (1.4.4)
```

I have also tried

```
pip install pymysql
```

And then edited the init.py file to have the following code:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Whilst keeping my databases variable the same as above. Doing this produces the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

I have the MySQL python connector downloaded and installed onto my system.

I have tried giving the empty ALLOWED_HOSTS variable within settings.py an argument of my localhost.

The MySQL server is running fine outside of Django and can be accessed on the terminal very successfully.

I replaced Engine in the Databases variable with:

```
mysql.connector.django
```

Which produced the following error code:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: try making the engine back to `django.db.backends.mysql` what happens now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question here, and considered deleting the post however it may help someone else out there. I ran the command

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Prior to changing the engine value within the DATABASES dictionary to:

```
'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
```

The MySQL database finally connected to my Django project

Comment: In addition to this I has to set `'OPTIONS': { 'use_pure': True, }`

Comment: I did all this. Still it says 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend

Comment: We had the same problem with this solution